# Regex to find substring and wrap it in tags - Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write code which finds all words that are in the following format

```
"some text":
```

So alphanumeric characters which are within " symbols and which end with the : symbol. My goal once I find these is to remove the " character and wrap the entire string in  tag. So after the code has run, the above text would look like this,

```
<strong>some text:</strong>
```

So I believe the regex to find such text for wrapping is the following (formatted for Java),

```
(\".*?\"):{1}
```

And by using the following code, I should be able to iterate through all the matches.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\".*?\"):{1}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToSearch);

while(matcher.find()) {
  String matchedGroup = matcher.group();
  matchedGroup = matchedGroup.replaceAll("\"", "");
  matchedGroup = "<strong>" + matchedGroup + "</strong>";
  
  // now what?
}
```

So I probably went about that all wrong.

Now that I've wrapped the word I wanted in a strong tag, how do I "put it back" where it was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you expect your double quotes to always be balanced, you may just use `String#replaceAll` here for a more terse solution:

```
String input = "Here is \"some text\": and also \"some other text\":";
String output = input.replaceAll("\"(.*?)\":", "<strong>$1:</strong>");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
Here is <strong>some text:</strong> and also <strong>some other text:</strong>
```